# Issue deploying to Render

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, render

I have been struggling to deploy to render.

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/opt/render/project/src/client/dist/index.html'**

My client/dist/index.html does exist but I believe it is not being built properly on Render as it works fine locally.

root package.json =

"scripts": {
"start": "node server/server.js",
"develop": "concurrently "cd server && npm run watch" "cd client && npm run dev"",
"install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
"build": "cd client && npm run build",
"render-build":"npm install && npm run build"
},

server.js =

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'));
});
```

}